# jQuery code lines from array

Tags: javascript, jquery

This works ok:

```
$('#icon1').live("hover", show_popup, hide_popup);
$('#icon2').live("hover", show_popup, hide_popup);
$('#icon3').live("hover", show_popup, hide_popup);
```

But this does not works and has no error:

```
var icons = ['#icon1', '#icon2', '#icon3'];
for (icon in icons)
    $(icon).live("hover", show_popup, hide_popup);
```

What is wrong with that code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `for in` loop works as:

```
for(var key in obj)
```

In an array, the keys are numeric indices, i.e. `0`, `1`, `2`, etc. The corresponding *value* each time is `obj[key]` (with `obj` being a normal object or an array).

You should use a `for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)` loop for arrays, but apart from that, this should work as well:

```
$("#icon1, #icon2, #icon3").live(...);
```

Or, if you want to match all `#iconXXX` elements:

```
$("[id^='icon']").live(...);
```

Note that if you're using jQuery 1.7 you can use `.on`, which is a normalized function for `.bind`/`.live` and should work neater.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the following code:

```
var icons = ['#icon1', '#icon2', '#icon3'];
for (var icon in icons) {
    $(icons[icon]).live("hover", show_popup, hide_popup);
}
```

Because in a for-in statement like `for (var prop in obj)`, `prop` here is actually a index or property name of the `obj` object. And if you want to refer to the property of a object, use `[]` expression.

By the way, when use a for-in loop, you would better do it as:

```
for (var prop in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        // do something with obj[prop]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To bind to all the items described in array, you can use Array.join function:

```
var icons = ['#icon1', '#icon2', '#icon3'];
$(icons.join(",")).live("hover", show_popup, hide_popup);
```